# How to save results of query into a new column, postgres

Tags: postgresql

How to add results of selecting query to a new column in already existing table in PostgreSQL in pgAdmin?

Results of the select query is an alteration of over columns in the same table.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: try something like this

with new_table as (
   SELECT id, 
          col1-col2 as diff
   from  yourtable 
)
update yourtable as yt
  set time_diff = yt.diff
from new_table yt
where yt.id = tr.id;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the column and update data afterwards (using the command line bundled in pgadmin):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMN colname coltype;
UPDATE tablename SET colname = yourexpression;
```

Comment: thanks, had the same thing, just had a problem with column name